# Proving that matrices in $O(2)$ are of one of two forms

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal, linear-groups

Given $A \in O(2)$, show that $A$ has one of the following two forms:

$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{matrix} \right) $$

$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & -\cos(\theta) \end{matrix} \right) $$

---

Suppose $A \in O(2)$, then we have that:

$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{matrix} \right) $$

Since $A \in O(2)$, it's columns are orthonormal with respect to the inner product $\langle x,y \rangle = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2$ and that $\det(A) = \pm 1$. Thus we arrive at the following system of equations:

$$a^2+b^2 = 1$$

$$c^2+d^2 = 1$$

$$ac+bd = 0$$

$$|ad-bc|=1$$

The first two equations say that $a,b,c,d$ all lie on the unit circle. So we have either $a = \sin(\theta)$ and $b=\cos(\theta)$ or that $a = \cos(\theta)$ and $b = \sin(\theta)$. A similar statement holds for $c$ and $d$.

Anyway, I'm a bit stuck. Am I going about this correctly? Help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your either/or is unnecessary: all unit vectors $(a,b)$ are expressible uniquely as $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for some $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. That leaves two possibilities for $(c,d)$, an orthogonal unit vector: either $(a,b)$ rotated $90^\circ$ clockwise, or counterclockwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a^2+b^2=1$, there is some $\theta\in\Bbb R$ such that $a=\cos\theta$ and $b=\sin\theta$. And, since $(c,d)$ is orthogonal to $(a,b)$,$$(c,d)=\lambda(-b,a)=(-\lambda\sin\theta,\lambda\cos\theta)$$for some $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. But$$\pm1=\begin{vmatrix}\cos\theta&-\lambda\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\lambda\cos\theta\end{vmatrix}=\lambda;$$so, $\lambda=\pm1$ and you're done.

Comment: $(c,d)$ is orthogonal to $(a,b)$ and thus $ac+bd=0$ and thus $\frac{-a}{b}=\frac{d}{c}$ and thus $\lambda(-b,a)=(c,d)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Hmm. Can you give some perspective on how we can conclude that $\lambda(-b,a)=(c,d)$ from the orthogonality? Sorry I'm a bit slow

Comment: It is clear that every vector of the form $\lambda(-b,a)$ ($\lambda\in\Bbb R$) is orthogonal to $(a,b)$. Can there be a vector $(c,d)$ orthogonal to $(a,b)$ which is *not* of that form? No, because otherwise $(-b,a)$ would be linearly independent (since none of them is a multiple of the other one) and therefore, since $\Bbb R^2$ is $2$-dimensional, $\{(-b,a),(c,d)\}$ would be a basis of $\Bbb R^2$. But then you would be able to write $(a,b)$ as $\alpha(-b,a)+\beta(c,d)$, and then $\alpha=\beta=0$, since $(a,b)$ is orthogonal to both vectors. But $\|(a,b)\|=1$.